# reiniciar modal al cerrarlo

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-6

estoy usando laravel 6 y estoy haciendo un modal para traer la info de otra tabla relacionada, la informacion se imprime correctamente pero si cierro el modal y lo vuelvo a abrir la info de dicha tabla relacionada se duplica

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_view_shop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="title_modal_view_shop"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="services" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Servicios*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <textarea id="services_list" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"> Cerrar  <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**así es como traigo la información:**

```
let services = data.service_shops;

services.forEach(element => document.getElementById('services_list').innerHTML += element.service.title);

$('#modal_view_shop').modal('show');
```

service_shops es la otra tabla y para acceder a lo demas tuve que hacer ese forEach

**imagen de como se ve cuando abro el modal por primera vez:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**imagen de como se ve si cierro el modal y lo vuelvo a abrir**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si sigo abriendo y cerrando diferentes modals me aparece la info de las imágenes junto la del modal que abrí

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tenia que inicializar `#services_list` antes de iterar el `array`.

```
document.querySelector('#services_list').innerHTML = '';
```